# C# - Convert list of enum values to list of strings

Tags: c#, enums

Let's say I have a C# `enum` called MyEnum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Apple,
    Banana,
    Carrot,
    Donut
}
```

And I have a `List<MyEnum>` such as:

```
List<MyEnum> myList = new List<MyEnum>();
myList.Add(MyEnum.Apple);
myList.Add(MyEnum.Carrot);
```

What is the **easiest** way to convert my `List<MyEnum>` to a `List<string>`? Do I have to create a new `List<string>` and then iterate through the enum list, one item at a time, converting each enum to a string and adding it to my new `List<string>`?

Comment: `var myNewList = myList.Select(t => t.ToString()).ToList();`

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are using a `List`, the easiest solution would be to use the `ConvertAll` method to obtain a new `List` containing `string` representations. Here's an example:

```
List<string> stringList = myList.ConvertAll(f => f.ToString());
```

There are other ways to accomplish this, but this way will get the job done and uses syntax that should be in whatever version of .NET you're using because it's been around for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list= (from action in (MyEnum[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)) select action.ToString()).ToList();
```